# How can I develop an in-site linking program with multiple dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, shopify

I need to develop a similar application of multiple dropdown that we use on our Shopify e-commerce [Site](https://kolayoto.com/) for links to all tire type pages within the site. I tried but I couldn't do it because I was not experienced enough in JS and Jquery and I don't know how to get started. Can you help me?

[image: The app we use on our Shopify Site]

I want to add the json value of the option selected in dropdowns to the end of the link below which should be in the "Find Now" (Hemen Bul) button.
https://kolayoto.com/collections/lastikleri?_=

If our choices are "Yaz", "225", "60" and "15". Our selections will be added to the end of the link and when we click the Find Now (Hemen Bul) button, it will direct us to the link below. https://kolayoto.com/collections/lastikleri?_=pf&pf_t_mevsim=Mevsim-Yaz&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Geni%C5%9Fli%C4%9Fi-225&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oran%C4%B1-60&pf_t_cap=Jant%20%C3%87ap%C4%B1-15

In this way, I will link to all season and tire type pages from the homepage.

```
Example Json file that I will use in the application.

{
  "mevsim": {
    "DörtMevsim": "pf&pf_t_diger_oezellikler=DiğerÖzellikler-4Mevsim",
    "Yaz": "pf&pf_t_mevsim=Mevsim-Yaz",
    "Kış": "pf&pf_t_mevsim=Mevsim-Kış"
  },
  "tabangenisligi": {
    "135": "&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-135",
    "145": "&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-145",
    "155": "&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-155",
    "165": "&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-165",
    "175": "&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-175",
    "185": "&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-185",
    "195": "&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-195",
    "205": "&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-205",
    "215": "&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-215",
    "225": "&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-225",
    "235": "&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-235",
    "245": "&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-245",
    "255": "&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-255"
  },
  "kesitorani": {
    "30": "&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-30",
    "35": "&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-35",
    "40": "&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-40",
    "45": "&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-45",
    "50": "&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-50",
    "55": "&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-55",
    "60": "&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-60",
    "65": "&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-65",
    "70": "&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-70",
    "75": "&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-75"
  },
  "jantcapi": {
    "13": "&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-13",
    "14": "&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-14",
    "15": "&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-15",
    "16": "&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-16",
    "17": "&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-17",
    "18": "&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-18",
    "19": "&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-19",
    "20": "&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-20"
  }
}
```

I don't know how to link Json values ​​to dropdowns and add them to the link in the "Find Now" button when these values ​​are selected.

As a new software developer, I really need this development and I am waiting for your help. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Should the link only work if there was a choice in all select boxes or should the user also be able to find all filtered entries if only in one of them is a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this: Add the url part as values of the options and add all selected values to the url. In the example I've only added a few options of each category as demonstration and on click of the "Find all" button the url appears in the console. To really go to the url, uncomment the line `location.href = url`.

```js
$("#find").on("click", function() {
  let mevsim = ($("#mevsim").val() == 0) ? "" : $("#mevsim").val();
  let tabangenisligi = ($("#tabangenisligi").val() == 0) ? "" : $("#tabangenisligi").val();
  let kesitorani = ($("#mevsim").val() == 0) ? "" : $("#kesitorani").val();
  let jantcapi = ($("#mevsim").val() == 0) ? "" : $("#jantcapi").val();
  let url = "https://kolayoto.com/collections/lastikleri?_=" + mevsim + tabangenisligi + kesitorani + jantcapi;
  console.log("url: " + url);
  /* location.href = url */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mevsim">
  <option value="0">Please select</option>
  <option value="pf&pf_t_diger_oezellikler=DiğerÖzellikler-4Mevsim">DörtMevsim</option>
  <option value="pf&pf_t_mevsim=Mevsim-Yaz">Yaz</option>
  <option value="pf&pf_t_mevsim=Mevsim-Kış">Kış</option>
</select><br /><br />
<select id="tabangenisligi">
  <option value="0">Please select</option>
  <option value="&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-135">135</option>
  <option value="&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-145">145</option>
  <option value="&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-155">155</option>
</select><br /><br />
<select id="kesitorani">
  <option value="0">Please select</option>
  <option value="&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-30">30</option>
  <option value="&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-35">35</option>
  <option value="&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-40">40</option>
</select><br /><br />
<select id="jantcapi">
  <option value="0">Please select</option>
  <option value="&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-13">13</option>
  <option value="&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-14">14</option>
  <option value="&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-15">15</option>
</select><br /><br />
<button id="find">
  Find Now
</button>
```

Update: As adding all url parts as values to the options is no choice, it's also possible to get them from the JSON. Note that the url parts don't need be option values anymore, this is just a leftover from the example code. Uncomment the line `location.href = url`to go to the URL on click of the "Find now" button.

```js
let data = {
  "mevsim": {
    "DörtMevsim": "pf&pf_t_diger_oezellikler=DiğerÖzellikler-4Mevsim",
    "Yaz": "pf&pf_t_mevsim=Mevsim-Yaz",
    "Kış": "pf&pf_t_mevsim=Mevsim-Kış"
  },
  "tabangenisligi": {
    "135": "&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-135",
    "145": "&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-145",
    "155": "&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-155",
    "165": "&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-165",
    "175": "&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-175",
    "185": "&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-185",
    "195": "&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-195",
    "205": "&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-205",
    "215": "&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-215",
    "225": "&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-225",
    "235": "&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-235",
    "245": "&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-245",
    "255": "&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-255"
  },
  "kesitorani": {
    "30": "&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-30",
    "35": "&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-35",
    "40": "&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-40",
    "45": "&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-45",
    "50": "&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-50",
    "55": "&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-55",
    "60": "&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-60",
    "65": "&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-65",
    "70": "&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-70",
    "75": "&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-75"
  },
  "jantcapi": {
    "13": "&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-13",
    "14": "&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-14",
    "15": "&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-15",
    "16": "&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-16",
    "17": "&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-17",
    "18": "&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-18",
    "19": "&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-19",
    "20": "&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-20"
  }
}

$("#find").on("click", function() {
let mevsim, tabangenisligi, kesitorani, jantcapi;
if($("#mevsim").val() == 0){
mevsim = "";
}
else {
   let selected = $("#mevsim").find("option:selected").text();
  
   $.each(data, function(i, val) {
    if (i == "mevsim") {
      $.each(val, function(key, value) {
        if (key == selected) {
          mevsim = value;
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
if($("#tabangenisligi").val() == 0){
tabangenisligi = "";
}
else {
   let selected = $("#tabangenisligi").find("option:selected").text();
  
   $.each(data, function(i, val) {
    if (i == "tabangenisligi") {
      $.each(val, function(key, value) {
        if (key == selected) {
          tabangenisligi = value;
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
if($("#kesitorani").val() == 0){
kesitorani = "";
}
else {
   let selected = $("#kesitorani").find("option:selected").text();
  
   $.each(data, function(i, val) {
    if (i == "kesitorani") {
      $.each(val, function(key, value) {
        if (key == selected) {
          kesitorani = value;
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
if($("#jantcapi").val() == 0){
jantcapi = "";
}
else {
   let selected = $("#jantcapi").find("option:selected").text();
  
   $.each(data, function(i, val) {
    if (i == "jantcapi") {
      $.each(val, function(key, value) {
        if (key == selected) {
          jantcapi = value;
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
  let url = "https://kolayoto.com/collections/lastikleri?_=" + mevsim + tabangenisligi + kesitorani + jantcapi;
  console.log("url: " + url);
  /* location.href= url */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mevsim">
  <option value="0">Please select</option>
  <option value="pf&pf_t_diger_oezellikler=DiğerÖzellikler-4Mevsim">DörtMevsim</option>
  <option value="pf&pf_t_mevsim=Mevsim-Yaz">Yaz</option>
  <option value="pf&pf_t_mevsim=Mevsim-Kış">Kış</option>
</select><br /><br />
<select id="tabangenisligi">
  <option value="0">Please select</option>
  <option value="&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-135">135</option>
  <option value="&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-145">145</option>
  <option value="&pf_t_genislik=Taban%20Genişliği-155">155</option>
</select><br /><br />
<select id="kesitorani">
  <option value="0">Please select</option>
  <option value="&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-30">30</option>
  <option value="&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-35">35</option>
  <option value="&pf_t_oran=Kesit%20Oranı-40">40</option>
</select><br /><br />
<select id="jantcapi">
  <option value="0">Please select</option>
  <option value="&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-13">13</option>
  <option value="&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-14">14</option>
  <option value="&pf_t_cap=Jant%20Çapı-15">15</option>
</select><br /><br />
<button id="find">
  Find Now
</button>
```

Comment: Hi Matthias, thank you so much for helping. I tried to add the code you sent to our Shopify site and succeeded in some of them. However, after selecting only a few options, 0s is added instead of the options that are not selected.
gyazo.com/7dc62df3463e0e4c446fc413bb807012
Also instead of adding the options one by one, can we take it from a json file with a loop? Because there are hundreds of product options and adding them one by one will cause both the tiresome and code complexity for the site.

Comment: The line location.href = url is uncommented in the code? And strange that 0s are added for not selected options, in case a value is 0 there should be nothing added. And yes, it's possible to take the url parts from the json file, it's just a bit more work to invest to do so. I'll let you know when I have adjusted it but it might take some time.

Comment: Yes, I just figured out the "location.href = url" section and now it works. After selecting Yaz and 145 in the first 2 options and leaving the last 2 blank, a link like this is created. https://kolayoto.com/collections/lastikleri?_=pf&pf_t_mevsim=mevsim-yaz&pf_t_genislik=taban%20geni%c5%9fli%c4%9fi-14500  and also you can preview the site in here https://xi568avjeriwydhj-25161465961.shopifypreview.com

Comment: Then I am waiting for your return to take the URL parts from the Json file and I continue to my research on this subject. Thank you very much again, best regards.

Comment: @BerkB. I've just updated my answer with a 2nd solution taking the values from the json file.

Comment: Hi @matthias_h, I tried the last json solution you sent and it is working, thank you very much, but a more suitable solution came to my mind about this application. I mentioned this solution in the post, at the bottom you can find it under the update title.

I know it has become more complicated but I really need to solve and learn this coding for this site I am working on. I look forward to your help, many thanks in advance and and best regards.

Comment: @BerkB. It would be better to make a new question with the new requirements as the original question was answered.

Comment: I opened a new question and marked this question as answered. New question link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62011241/how-can-i-develop-an-in-site-product-filtering-program-with-multiple-dropdown   I would really apreciate if you help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214623/discussion-between-berk-b-and-matthias-h).